# C++ Efficient Element-wise Matching of two Matrices

Tags: c++, performance, vectorization, eigen, broadcast

I am using C++ and the Eigen library to complete a matching task. However, the result is highly inefficient. The following will describe the task and my current solution.

### Task

The task involves two large maps of the same size, `mapL` and `mapR`. The matching process occurs row-wise. For example, an element in the `r-th` row of `mapL` will match with an element in the `r-th` row of `mapR`. The values of the two matching elements may not be exactly the same and therefore I need to look for the element in `mapR` with the smallest difference.

To compute the difference, I go through the following steps:

1. Extract an element in the `r-th` row of `mapL`.
2. Extract the `r-th` row of `mapR`.
3. Subtract the row of `mapR` by the element of `mapL`).
4. Repeat the above steps for every element in `mapL`.

### Example

An example would be helpful to understand the above process. Let's say we have

```
mapL = [ 1  2  3  4, 5; 
         6  7  8  9 10;
        11 12 13 14 15];
mapR = [ 5  4  3  2, 1; 
        10  9  8  7  6;
        15 14 13 12 11];
```

For the first element in `mapL`, I would like to obtain a vector `difference` for some subsequent computations

```
difference = [5 4 3 2 1] - [1] = [4 3 2 1 0];
```

### Current Solution

When building the C++ code, I tried to vectorize the process by using `.replicate` and `.colwise`. The following shows an example code:

```
int nRow = 1800;
int nCol = 2000;

// Setup two random maps for illustration purposes
MatrixXf mapL = MatrixXf::Random(nRow, nCol);
MatrixXf mapR = MatrixXf::Random(nRow, nCol);

// Initialize some parameters
VectorXf rowL;
MatrixXf rowR(1, nCol);
MatrixXf repeatR;
MatrixXf difference;

// Loop through every row
for (int r = 0; r < nRow; r++) {

    // Extract a row from mapL and mapR
    rowL = mapL.row(r);
    rowR = mapR.row(r);

    // Repeat rowR along the col direction
    repeatR = rowR.replicate(nCol, 1);

    // Compute the difference by .colwise
    difference = repeatR.colwise()-=rowL;

    /* 
    Some other codes after the difference is computed
    */ 
}
```

### Problem

The above code takes around 61s on my machine (VS 2017, Release mode, x64) to iterate through every row. I have implemented a similar code in MATLAB and it only takes around 6s. Is there any way that I can improve the efficiency of the C++ code? I am pretty new to C++ and therefore please let me know if I have missed any important concepts. Thank you very much!

### Edit

After some more tests, I found a more efficient way to complete the task. Profiling my original code shows that the `.replicate` and `.colwise` operations consume a significant amount of computational power (~90%). Using a nested loop takes < 3s to complete the same task. The new code is as follows:

```
int nRow = 1800;
int nCol = 2000;

MatrixXf mapL = MatrixXf::Random(nRow, nCol);
MatrixXf mapR = MatrixXf::Random(nRow, nCol);

VectorXf rowL;
ArrayXf rowR(1, nCol);
ArrayXf difference;

for (int r = 0; r < nRow; r++) {
    rowL = mapL.row(r);
    rowR = mapR.row(r).array();
    for (int c = 0; c < nCol; c++) {
        difference = rowR - rowL(c);
    }
}
```

Comment: `// Extract a row from mapL and mapR` -- I haven't used Eigen, but is there a reason to actually "extract" a row?  Is it possible just to a reference to the existing row?  What exactly does `row(r)` return?  Is it a reference?  If it does return a reference, then your code seems to be unnecessarily making copies of the row, i.e. `VectorXf& rowL = mapL.row(r);` would seem to be faster *if* that `row()` function returns a reference.

Comment: That's an O(n^2) algo. If you sort the rows before matching, you can do this in O(n log n).

Comment: Thanks for the comments. The `row()` function in fact occupies a very small amount of the computational load. Profiling the original code shows that `.replicate` and `.colwise` consume about 90% of the computational load. After changing to a nested loop, the speed is improved significantly. The new code is included in **Edit**.

Comment: Please run your code (with smaller sizes) and debugging enabled first. At least in your second snippet `ArrayXf rowR(1, nCol)` should fail at runtime (for `nCol>1`). Also, please post [mre]s, and make sure that intermediate results are actually used (otherwise, the compiler may decide to optimize them away).

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions:

- By default, Eigen stores matrices in column-major order. It would probably help here to use row-major order instead by defining

  ```
  using RowMajorMatrixXf = Matrix<float, Dynamic, Dynamic, RowMajor>;
  ```

  and working with that instead of `MatrixXf` so that the rows are contiguous in memory.
- The `.row(r)` method returns an expression object that does not itself copy memory. But assigning it to VectorXf or ArrayXf makes a copy. You could eliminate the copy by holding on to the expression object like `decltype(mapL)::RowXpr rowL = mapL.row(r)`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I turned out using OpenCV's `parallel_for_` to complete the task in 0.1s. I thought that the loop would be slow but it wasn't. Anyway, thanks for sharing your knowledge in Eigen. I will definitely put that in my note.